# Is there a good way to map a function over a list to lists exclusively of a certain depth?

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have some ragged list.  If some elements have some depth $n$, then is there a way I can map a function to only those elements?

I.e., for some list `foo`,

```
foo = {1, {2, 3}, {4, 5, {6, 7}}, {8}, {9}}
```

The result should then be for $n=2$:

```
{1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {4, 5, {6, 7}}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}
```

I want to apply a function bar to all parts of it that are of depth 2, and depth 2 only.  So far, I have this attempt:

```
# /. (p_List /; Depth[p] == 2) :> (bar /@ p) & /@ foo
(* {1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {4, 5, {bar[6], bar[7]}}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}} *)
```

As you can see, pattern matching looks at ALL lists, so I can't really use what I have.  I suspect there could be some better, more functional solution to this (possibly using Scan, Reap, and Sow)?

Comment: It was a good idea to withhold awarding the checkmark until a few more answers came in. They were worth the wait. And halirutan apparently spotted just what you were looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve the requested output it is not sufficient to `Map` the function bar at a specific level. What you maybe want to express is *map the function on level 1 if it consists only of list of numbers*

```
Map[If[MatchQ[#, {__Integer}], bar /@ #, #] &, foo, {1}]

(*
  {1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {4, 5, {6, 7}}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}
*)
```

Another possibility is to use `Replace` and a specific level. But the idea is the same

```
Replace[foo, l : {__Integer} :> bar /@ l, {1}]
```

Comment: This solution is what I'm looking for.  But how does pattern matching for `l:{__Integer}` not pick up {6,7}?  Is that not a list of an integer sequence?

Comment: Yes, but the `Map` and the `Replace` act only on the first level. This means does not see `{6,7}` it sees `{4,5,{6,7}}` which does not match!

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I confused my `/.` with `Replace`, whereas it actually is `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: +1 For a good read of the motivation behind the question.

Comment: @DavidCarraher that's funny. I upvoted your other answer seconds ago because you extended your explanation ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Level 2 of `foo` is:

```
Level[foo, {2}]
```

> {2, 3, 4, 5, {6, 7}, 8, 9}

So if you try to map `bar` onto level 2, you will get:

```
Map[bar, foo, {2}]
```

> {1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {bar[4], bar[5], bar[{6, 7}]}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}

---

Let's look at the structure of `foo`, using `TreeForm[foo]`:

[image: treeform]

If you really want to obtain `{1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {4, 5, {6, 7}}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}`, you should use `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[bar, foo, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}]
```

> {1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {4, 5, {6, 7}}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}

Comment: Now I feel a bit silly for asking...  But you had to use specific positions for the `MapAt` function.  What if you didn't know `foo`?

Comment: @VF1 Not at all. This sort of issue is easy to stumble on.

Comment: By the way, you feel free to hold off awarding the check until you've received more input. There are several ways to skin the cat.

Comment: David, I think your initial `Map` results are off, it should give: `{1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {bar[4], bar[5], 
  bar[{6, 7}]}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}`.

Comment: Good catch. I must have copied the answer from some other place.

Answer (score 3):

Mapping f[] over foo

```
 Map[f[#] &, foo, {2}]
```

returns

```
{1, {f[2], f[3]}, {f[4], f[5], f[{6, 7}]}, {f[8]}, {f[9]}}
```

Which agrees with the comment above. If you wanted to apply the function at a certain level, then you don't have to know about the list in advance; just specify the level as

```
Map[function[#]&,list,{level}]
```

or some version of that construction.  By the way, mapping is a much easier way to apply functions to lists.

Comment: Perhaps my title is misleading.  I actually want what my "expectation" shows.  I'll reword the title to say "Is there a good way to map a function over a list to lists exclusively of a certain depth?"

Comment: But doesn't `Map[...]` map the function over all parts of the list of a certain level, instead of just the ones with only a certain depth (which is what I want)?

Comment: So it's not at certain depth, but instead, at certain places?

Comment: You could think of it that way.  I only want parts that are one-dimensional lists to be affected.

Answer (score 3):

I find your question and examples rather opaque.  Some operations that may be what you're looking for, or at least usefully related:

```
Map[bar, foo, {2}]
```

> ```
> {1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {bar[4], bar[5], bar[{6, 7}]}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}
> ```

```
Map[bar, foo, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {1, bar[{2, 3}], {4, 5, bar[{6, 7}]}, bar[{8}], bar[{9}]}
> ```

```
Replace[foo, x_Integer :> bar@x, {2}]
```

> ```
> {1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {bar[4], bar[5], {6, 7}}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}
> ```

```
Replace[foo, x : {__Integer} :> bar /@ x, {1}]
```

> ```
> {1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {4, 5, {6, 7}}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}
> ```

```
Replace[foo, p_List /; Depth[p] == 2 :> bar /@ p, {1}]
```

> ```
> {1, {bar[2], bar[3]}, {4, 5, {6, 7}}, {bar[8]}, {bar[9]}}
> ```

On reflection I suspect the last one is what you're actually seeking.

Comment: In regard to the last one (which is indeed something I'm looking for), what the difference with what you wrote compared to what I wrote in my question?  Is it that `/.` mean `ReplaceAll`, which looks at all levels for lists of depth two?

Comment: @VF1 `/.` is indeed `ReplaceAll`, and it tries to match the given pattern at *all* levels.  `Replace` only looks for the pattern at the specified level(s).  Your `Map` construct would be equivalent to `Replace[foo, p_List /; Depth[p] == 2 :> bar /@ p, {1, -1}]` meaning from the first level to the last, but *not* "level zero" which is the entire expression.